# Checking two strings for approximate match in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to check approximately similarity of strings.

Here is a criteria that I use for that.

1) The order of the words is important
2) The words can have 80% of similarity.

Example:

```
$string1 = "How much will it cost to me" //string in vocabulary (all "right" words is here)
$string2 = "How much does costs it "   //"costs" instead "cost" -is a deliberate mistake (user input);
```

Algoritm:
1) Check the similarity of words and create clean string with "right" words (according to the order it appear in vocabulary).
OUTPUT: "how much it **cost**"
2) create clean string with "right" words in order it appear in user input.
OUTPUT: "how much cost it"
3)Compare two outputs - if not the same - return no, else if same return yes.

Any suggestions?

I started to write a code, but i'm not familiar with a tools in PHP, so i don't know how to do it rationally and efficiently.

It looks more like javascript/php

```
$string1="how much will it cost for me" ;
$string2= "how much does costs it";

function compareStrings($string1, $string2) {

    if (strlen($s1)==0 || strlen($s2)==0) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (strpos($s1, "  ")!==false) {
        $s1 = str_replace("  ", " ", $s1);
    }
    while (strpos($s2, "  ")!==false) {
        $s2 = str_replace("  ", " ", $s2);
    }

    $ar1 = explode(" ",$s1);
    $ar2 = explode(" ",$s2);
    $array1 = array_flip($ar1);
    $array2 = array_flip($ar2);
    $l1 = count($ar1);
    $l2 = count($ar2);

 $meaning="";
    $rightorder=""

    for ($i=0;$i<=$l1;$i++) {


        for ($j=0;$j<=$l2;$j++) {

         $k=   similar_text($array1[i], $array2[j], $perc).PHP_EOL;
if ($perc>=85) {
    $meaning=$meaning." ".$array1[j]; //generating a string of the first output
    $rightorder[i]= array1[i]; //generating the array with second output

}

        }


    }

}
```

The idea thet the $meaning will get "how much it cost"
and $rightorder will get

```
$rightorder[0]='how'
$rightorder[1]='much'
$rightorder[2]=''
$rightorder[3]='cost'
$rightorder[4]='it'
```

after then i will somehow onvert it back to string "how much cost it"

and compare those two.

```
if ("how much cost it"=="how much it cost") return true; else return false.
```

Comment: check out the [levenshtein()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) and [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function offered by PHP, they might fit the bill.

Comment: Also [soundex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php)

Comment: You should read the question. I know this function, but the question is more complicated

Answer (score 1):

Your problem belongs to the science of NLP (Natural Language Processing).

Each issue mentioned in the question has a filed of study of its own:

- Splitting a string into words is [tokenization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization). It seems trivial in English, however it is not in other languages, like German. There is also a problem of how to parse punctuation marks.
- Creating "right words" is called stemming. There is a number of tools to do that. If your words are in English you may try [Porter Stemming Algorithm](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/php.txt). Other languages may have their own stemming techniques, usually a dictionary algorithm exists.
- Calculating the similarity of string based on the individual word occurrences is called "[Cosine Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)". There is a number of other techniques. There is alse a problem od [synonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonymy) and [polysemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy)

I hope it help as your problem is a mixture of the above-mentioned problems.

Comment: Yes i know what is NLP, but i don't want to dive into it. Here is my simplified solution for that (good for latinic languages)